# Macro copy and paste based on date

Tags: vba, checkbox

I have a workbook in which I am trying to keep track of bicycles in stock and sold. I have worksheets for Current Inventory, January Sales, February Sales, March Sales, ... , December Sales, 2013 Total Sales.

In Current Inventory I have Bicycle Manufacturer in A2, Bicycle Model in B2, Bike Type in C2, Price in D2, Serial Number in E2, Date Sold in F2, and Sold in G2. In the G column  I have a form control check box.

What I want to do is when I click the check box that bike and all its information gets copy and pasted into the proper worksheet (eg. if it is sold on 08/13/2013 it gets sorted into the August Sales worksheet and 2013 Total Sales worksheet) as well as the 2013 Total Sales worksheet. In addition I want the row that is checked to change color from black to green. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your checkboxes are not crossing to two different rows. Once you have ensured it, then I would do something like this:

1. Assign same Macro to all the Checkboxes.
2. In the macro, I will add the Following Code:

   ```
   Dim shp As Shape
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim currentRowNumber As Long

   Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
   Set rng = shp.BottomRightCell
   currentRowNumber = rng.Row

   MsgBox "Currently, you are working on Row no " & currentRowNumber
   ```

Once you have got the Row number, then you can easily find the values and write the code accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
V

Answer (score 0):

First think about using a regular Cell instead of Checkbox (easier and better)
Then try the code bellow:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim checkedMark As String
Dim currentRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
checkedMark = "X"

If Target.Rows.Count <> 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If TypeName(Target.Value) <> "String()" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If UCase(Target.Value) <> checkedMark Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Columns <> 7 Then
    Exit Sub
End If


currentRow = Target.Row

Range(Cells(currentRow, 1), Cells(currentRow, 7)).Copy

With Sheets(BD_SHEET)
    lastRow = .Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

With Cells(currentRow, 1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```